# Xcode keyboard shortcut for Find Anything

Tags: xcode

In `JetBrains` IDE's - in particular `AppCode` or `Intellij` - there is a `Find Anything` command that is `Command-Shift-A` that allows searching for any IDE related Action in a convenient modal dialog.  Is there an equivalent in the `Xcode`?

An example use-case:  there are SOF answers mentioning `Solution -> Open Target`. I can not find either `Solution` or `Open Target` in the Menus.  I even employed the `CheatSheet` application and pored over every available shortcut.   If there were a `Find Anything` then I could put in the terms `Solution` and/or `Open Target` and a list of related Xcode/IDE actions would be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> will jump you to the “Find navigator” where you can search through your current project. This is great if you want to do free-form searches anywhere in your project and includes options for case sensitivity, context (e.g. search for anywhere for text or just expressions beginning with the search term), regular expression searches, etc. See [Find and replace content in a project](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev35dbcdcf8).

The <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (the letter “o”, not the number zero) will pull up the “Open Quickly...” search dialog where you can search for symbols in both your project as well as the frameworks. See [Open a file containing a symbol](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev524eff3ce).

Comment: Thanks those are helpful.  Is there a shortcut for `Recent files` or similar? I looked in the `Key bindings` and did not find it - but maybe has a different name.

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by “recent files”. Down at the bottom of the project navigator (command+1) there is a “recent files” button. (If you’re using source control, the button next to that one is useful when working on a PR on a project with tons of files, too,) Or if you’re looking for recent projects, see the “Welcome to Xcode” window (command+shift+1).

Comment: @javadba - If you’re looking for techniques to make yourself really efficient in Xcode, see Hacking with Swift’s [Xcode tips and tricks](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/166/xcode-tips-and-tricks-part-one).

Comment: thx `command+1` is bringing up a `Identity and Type` sidebar afaict.  I did see there's a button for `recent files` but reaching for the trackpad is slow and distracting. I want to navigate purely with the keyboard.  I'm looking at the `tips` link now

Comment: @javadba By the way, if you want to jump between recent files, control+command+left and right arrow will jump between recent files, too.

Comment: that's the kind of info I'd look for: unfortunately it is not listed in the `Key Bindings` . Is there a more comprehensive reference available for the shortcuts?

Comment: @javadba They are listed in “Key Bindings” under the “Navigate” menu under “Go Forward” and “Go Back”.

Comment: ok thx - i'll re-read the key bindings to understand the nomenclature

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode replacement for Android Studio's/Jetbrains "Find Anything" command (which is not the Quick Open) is:

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>

This opens the Help menu ready to type into the Find Anything search, where you can search for Xcode's own commands, for example `Reveal`:

[image: xcode search in menus]

Answer (score 1):

I like the `Open Quickly` and `Quick Actions` shortcuts. They let you jump to any file or action from a search bar:

[image]

[image]